# Get Element by Name/ID

Tags: html, internet-explorer, powershell

I am trying to automate logging into a website to run a report for our ticking system.

I am able to login and get into the system. However I am having an issue clicking the report button.

I have tried many many many variations however no success.

This is the HTML Code for the report button.

```
<td class="navigation" nowrap="" valign="bottom"><span id="tab_view4" class="off" onmouseover="this.className='on'" onmouseout="if(iViewType!=4) this.className='off'"><a href="/SWiseWeb/null.html" target="spider2" onclick="return ChangeView(4);">
```

Report Bananna

I have tried

```psh
$ie.document.getElementsByName("tab_view4").submit()
$ie.document.getElementsByName("tab_view4").submit()
$ie.document.getElementsByName("tab_view4").click()
$ie.document.getElementsByID("tab_view4").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` and `name` are different attributes. To get an element with the **`id="tab_view4"`** use `$ie.document.getElementById("tab_view4")` (without "s" as IDs are supposed to be unique in an HTML document).

Comment: Nogo doing this..   Method invocation failed because [mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass] does not contain a method named 'getElementByName'.
At C:\Building EXE\In Dev\TechXL report\TECCHXL.PS1:46 char:1
+ $ie.document.getElementByName("tab_view4").click()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: @JayCee360 Read again. Pay particular attention to the method name in my answer.

Comment: I am sorry I didnt clear the powershell ISE. It threw an error again. I am a newbie learning. :)    You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Building EXE\In Dev\TechXL report\TECCHXL.PS1:46 char:1
+ $ie.document.getElementById("tab_view4").click()

Comment: @JayCee360 Then the document apparently doesn't contain an element with the ID `tab_view4`. Does the page consist of frames or contain iframes?

Comment: @JayCee360 That doesn't say anything about whether the *page* has frames/iframes or not. Also, please don't post code in comments. It becomes unreadable. Edit your question if you need to provide additional information. Also, it seems like it's the `<span>` element having the ID `tab_view4`, but you need to click the nested anchor element.

Comment: @JayCee360 Addendum: it might be a good idea to check the output of `$ie.Document.body.innerHtml`. That should give you more information about the page structure.

Comment: I tweaked it to have the entire span. If you need the entire source then let me know.

Comment: @JayCee360 Like I said: check the value of `$ie.Document.body.innerHtml`.